# Lock quick launch area in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I would like my shortcuts that are pinned to the taskbar to always appear to the left of the buttons for the running programs.

Occasionally, a running program button will appear to left of one of the pinned shortcuts, is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way for that to happen is if you drag it there, or if one of the programs that are running is also pinned to the quick launch bar.